# ngFor and ngIf not working

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, ngfor, angular-ng-if

can you help here guys please

so i'm trying to display the data i got from the backend but seems like *ngFor not working and want to return only enabled sizes how to do it with ngIf

this is the template

```
<select name="sizeAndPrice" class="form-control">
  <option [value]="size.value" *ngFor="let size of item.field_prices.set_details"> 
   <span>{{(item.commerce_price.amount/100) + size.field_product_size[0].options[0].price}} </span>
   <span>{{(item.commerce_price.amount/100) + sizefield_product_size[0].options[0].price}} EGP</span>
  </option>
</select>
```

this is the data i get (the part i'm looping on)

```
commerce_price :                 {amount:12000},
      field_prices : {                
        set_details : {
          field_product_size : [
            {
              enabled :                  0,
              options : [
                {
                  enabled :              1,
                  price_op :             "plus",
                  price :                0
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              enabled :                  1,
              options : [
                {
                  enabled :              1,
                  price_op :             "plus",
                  price :                30
                }

              ]
            }
          ],

          field_sizes_discounts : [
            {
              enabled :                  1,
              options : [
                {
                  enabled :              1,
                  price_op :             "minus",
                  price :                "0"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              enabled :                  1,
              options : [
                {
                  enabled :              1,
                  price_op :             "minus",
                  price :                "15"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
        }
      }
```

so i need to display prices of each size and then subtract the discount and show hide that size if not enabled

Comment: What you say `*ngFor and *ngIf are not working`, what is the behaviour? What is the behaviour you're expecting? Are there any error messages?

Comment: You can not combine a `*ngFor` and a `*ngIf` in one html tag

Comment: okay but if but if i removed the ngIf still doesn't work ,, 
plus how to filter the ngIf

Comment: oh it works but what i need to do is to loop the set details to access the discount as well that is not working 
let me edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using *ngFor and *ngIf on same element which is not allowed.
Solution is to wrap span content with `<ng-container>`

```
   <select name="sizeAndPrice" class="form-control">
          <option [value]="size.value" *ngFor="let size of item.field_prices.set_details.field_product_size" "> 
           <ng-container `*ngIf="item.field_prices.set_details.field_product_size.enabled; else notEnabled"`> 
             <span>{{(item.commerce_price.amount/100) + size.options[0].price}} </span>
             <span>{{(item.commerce_price.amount/100) + size.options[0].price}} EGP</span>
          </ng-container>
           <ng-template #notEnabled><option></option> </ng-template>
          </option>
        </select>
```

Comment: this works fine but please look at the question edit again cause i wrote it wrong

Comment: Could you tell what is wrong now? Are there any errors on console?

Comment: okay works fine but the ng template is now showing an empty select option -- so how to delete it if not enabled

Comment: if you want to show empty option when no option available create template for no option and reference it in ngContainer #notEnabled. updated the answer. Please check now

Comment: no the first answer is showing empty option and i do not want empty option

Comment: USE *ngIf="size.enabled" (not *ngIf="item.field_prices.set_details.field_product_size.enabled)